# Apache2 - Install several certificates for different domains without virtualhosts

Tags: apache, symfony, ssl

I have an application written in Symfony2 which basically is a website builder. There are many domains pointing to the server IP, the php app inspects the request and displays the contents associated to that domain.

Is there a way to install ssl certificates on Apache for every domain, every domain should have its own certificate, whithout having any Virtuahost?

Apache is configured to answer to every request on port 80 and 443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache permits only 1 certificate per configured host.

So to achieve your goals, you will either need to use a multidomain certificate and include all domain in that certificate.  By default, most vendors limit you to 100 domains per certificate.  Note that www.domain.com and domain.com count as 2 different domains for the purpose of multi-domain certificates.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/UnderstandingMultiUseSSLCertificates

Otherwise, you will need to configure Vhosts for each domain. Depending on your OS, you may be able to use SNI with Apache so you don't need unique IPs for each domain.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Thanks for the directions. Do you think would be a better solution to add manually a new VirtualHost for every domain and then setting there the ssl certificate for that domain? I am asking this because the every domain must have a their own certificate. Also, is this possible with only one IP?

Comment: The approach really depends on your business needs. If it is only 4-5 domains, then a multi-domain certificate works well. If it is 100's then virtualhosts will be needed.  In terms of using one IP, I already answered that above.